# How to make secure backup in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I tried to understand the code but I have some difficulties in it.
`crontab -e` is crontab schedule formatpm 9pm at night every Sunday,
but it seem to me it is encrypted. 
Can any one explain it?

```
Crontab -e 0 21 * * 0 zip -P passw0rd -r /var/backup/secure.zip /home/$USER >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: `I tried to understand the code but I have some difficulties` .... this does not describe the difficulties in any way ........ what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: something like 2>&1 what does it mean  and also /dev/null   and also $USER i understand that the code wile make schedule -p pass0rd it is optional  /var/backup/secure.zip here  it it means we make new file called secure.zip

Comment: What exactly is your question? `How to make secure backup in Ubuntu Linux` or to understand the command mentioned in your post? For the first one, there are lots of answers, for the second one, just type `man crontab`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `crontab -e` lets you edit your crontab and if you add the line `0 21 * * 0 zip -P passw0rd -r /var/backup/secure.zip /home/$USER >/dev/null 2>&1`, save and exit your editor, then you have created a new entry that runs the command each Sunday at 9pm.

You can use `crontab -l` to display the content of your crontab on stdout without editing it.

The command creates a zip file `/var/backup/secure.zip` of the content of your home directory `/home/$USER` recursively (`-r`) and uses the password option `-P passw0rd` to encrypt it with password "passw0rd".

The `>/dev/null 2>&1` at the end is used to prevent any output of the zip command to stdout and stderr to prevent cron from sending any mails (if successful or in the event of an error).

To unzip the zip file, you will have to enter the password if you use `unzip secure.zip`, or use `unzip -P passw0rd secure.zip`.

Comment: How is this an **answer**???

Comment: @user5325 This is an answer explaining the crontab entry of the question and **not** "How to make a secure backup". In my opinion OP has chosen a bad title for the question. Is something wrong with the crontab explanation or why do I get the downvotes?